# CSYMGenerator Can't Open XCode Project Run

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, macos-high-sierra

I got

> CSYMGenerator cannot be Opened because of a problem

message while running my project.

[image]

**OS**: High Sierra v10.13

**XCode**: 9.0

> Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing
>
> Application Specific Information: dyld: launch, loading dependent
>   libraries
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/CrashlyticsLanguageSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashlyticsLanguageSupport
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/XPCServices/CSYMGenerator.xpc/Contents/MacOS/CSYMGenerator
>   Reason: image not found

**Crashlytics**  Version 3.8.3 (120)

**Fabric** Version 2.6.14 (1285)

Comment: Thanks! Can you use the Crashlytics upload symbols script and let me know the output?

Comment: I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Can you quit Fabric.app and try removing the local cache by running: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac

Then, do a clean and build.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I will try this.

Comment: problem still exist. @Alexizamerican

Comment: Same issue here. Is this related to fabric app compatibility with Sierra? @ToddBurner

Comment: What version of the Fabric app are you using @LalKrishna and @D_D? Go to "Fabric" -> "About Fabric" to see.

Comment: Version 2.6.14 (1285) @Alexizamerican

Comment: Did you install the Fabric frameworks via CocoaPods, through the Fabric App, or manually via fabric.io/kits? When does this error appear- is it when you build your app? We're trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fabric App. Yes, Build & Run. Actually its working fine with previous Mac OS, After updating Mac OS to `High Sierra v10.13` this error is shown up.

Comment: @Alexizamerican I think this Crashlytics doesn't report crash. I just make `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];` & it doesn't appeared on my dashboard. Is this due to this issue? What should I done for make it working?

Comment: @D_D did this fixed for you? Is crashlytics able to report crash?

Comment: @LalKrishna it's possible that this issue is causing your crashes to not appear if we can't generate and upload a cSYM. While we look into this, check out https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script for instructions on how to upload your dSYM using the upload-symbols script.

Comment: crashlytics reported issues correctly. But it takes too long to appear on my dashboard. @Alexizamerican

Comment: @LalKrishna not yet , waiting for fabric update.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We've been able to reproduce this locally and are working on a fix.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :]  Hope you guys can fix this soon. :-]

Comment: We've found the issue and are testing out the fix internally.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the Fabric app and this error went away.

According to a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587492/why-does-fabric-mac-app-opens-automatically-when-project-is-running/47635142#47635142) by [Mike Bonnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell) who works at Google on Crashlytics at Google, Fabric app has not been used in years.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18223925)

Comment: @bschaeffer Read it again. It does answer the question - but it did have superfluous "thanks" stuff that could be edited out.

Comment: please check the question's comment section. You can find @Mike Bonnel accepted this as a Bug on Fabric. & They are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.  To get it to work I ran

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
```

AND I deleted the Fabric app off my computer.

This is not an ideal workaround, but at least I can build and run my app now.  This is definitely not ideal, but the issue went away.  I was using `XCode 8.2.1` on the latest `High Sierra`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ready tried this as Alexizamerican's commented already. There is no issues with build & run. It already works smoothly. Also my crashlytics reported Crashes too. I don't know why the CSYM message appeared.