# Why does Fabric mac app opens automatically when project is running?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-fabric

As part of fabric integration I have installed Fabric mac app, 
I found that whenever I run the project(I am running iOS app through XCode), the Fabric app also gets launched automatically,

My Questions are:

- Why it automatically launches when running project ?
- Is there a way I can stop this happening ?

FYI: The same happens even when the app is running in simulator.

Comment: Could you tell me, which applications do you use in Fabric? is there fastlane in?

Comment: try this: http://www.techradar.com/how-to/software/operating-systems/how-to-remove-startup-items-in-os-x-1305627

Comment: @missionMan: Haven't done fastlane seperatly, I just use Fabrics for Beta version upload.

Comment: @Daljeet: Its not start up items related, it starts only when the project runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. It's an odd behavior that you're seeing and is most likely due to an old version of the Run Script. Years ago, the run script build phase required the Fabric app to be present in order to handle the actual uploading of the dSYMs. We would move the dSYMs during the build of the app to a location that the Fabric app would then asynchronously upload them. That behavior was changed a long way back, but it's possible a new version never was included. The current version is: `Fabric.framework/run 1.6.2 (205)`

I'd check the version by running ./run -v from the project and update your Fabric and Crashlytics frameworks.

You can also remove Fabric.app completely from your system and switch to using CocoaPods or manual installation [instructions](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install). It hasn't been required to use for a couple of years.

Comment: So, If I update the Fabric framework and update the script(by doing the setup process again freshly) will this issue be resolved? I am asking since I like to use the Fabric mac app, it's nice and helpful.

Comment: Yes, I would expect that to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to update Fabrics and Crashlytics.